# rhive.connect error - file:///rhive/lib/2.0-0.0/rhive_udf.jar does not exist

Tags: r

I am facing an error while connecting R with Hive using the rhive package. The package was installed perfectly but it is returning error while using rhive.connect. Please note the following:

1. Rserve is running as a daemon
2. R and Hive are installed on separate servers but within the same cluster
3. RHive was built from source using git. The version is 2.0-0.0
4. I am connecting to hiveserver running on port 10000
5. The error message says "file:///rhive/lib/2.0-0.0/rhive_udf.jar does not exist" although the file is there (in linux directory) and the entire directory and file has full permissions.

Below is the snapshot of the error:

```
library(RHive)

Loading required package: rJava

Loading required package: Rserve

rhive.env()

hadoop home: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hadoop
hive home: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hive

rhive.connect("10.0.192.108")

14/07/04 00:45:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hadoop/client/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
14/07/04 00:45:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Warning:
        +----------------------------------------------------------+
        + / hiveServer2 argument has not been provided correctly.  +
        + / RHive will use a default value: hiveServer2=TRUE.      +
        +----------------------------------------------------------+

Error: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: file:///rhive/lib/2.0-0.0/rhive_udf.jar does not exist.
```

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify defaultFS parameter. RHive tries to write to filesystem instead of HDFS if you don't give defaultFS parameter.

```
rhive.connect("10.0.192.108", defaultFS="hdfs://10.0.192.108:8020")
```